# PHP Error: Function name must be a string in

Tags: php

I added following few lines on top of my PHP code, but it is giving error
the *error is*

> Function name must be a string in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 3

```
 if(!isset($_session)) {
 $session_start();}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong:

```
 if(!isset($_session)) {
 $session_start();}
```

`$session_start()` should be `session_start()`. `$` is for variables, `session_start()` is a function, not a variable, thus, `$` is not required.

Also, it must be capitalised as it's a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array. (*Credits to @AkshayPrakash for pointing out*)

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();}
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: thanks now  not giving any error.

Comment: @shubhamsingh Maybe accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark below the upvote/ downvote buttons, thanks

Comment: Also `$_session` should be `$_SESSION`

Comment: @AkshayPrakash Thanks for pointing out, updated post

Comment: Might want to tell the OP ***why*** that change should be made, instead of a copy paste fix

Comment: @HankyPanky Updated post to elaborate on the change, thanks